# querySelectorAll not selecting all elements

Tags: javascript

```js
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    function $(elements) {
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll(elements);
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
             var item = matches[i];   
        }
        return item;
    }
}

$('div.test').style.fontSize = '36px';
```

```html
<div class="test">asdf</div>
<div class="asdfd">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

I'd like to select all elements using querySelectorAll, but this seems to only affect the last element.

Comment: You're taking a very strange route to converting a NodeList into something else in order to fail anyway (assuming you meant to return something other than a single node, which is the only way that `style.fontSize` is ever going to work).

Comment: How can I apply the style change outside of the loop and utilize my function?

Comment: To whoever has downvoted every answer apart from @CarlMarkham's without leaving a corresponding comment, I and many others consider it rather impolite.

Comment: Just to be clear, it wasn't me.

Comment: Incidentally, since your question seems to be more about "how can I replicate jQuery's selector and chaining syntax," there's a very good article here: http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/

Comment: Ok. I did wonder, but didn't want to suggest it without knowing!

Comment: Carl, Nathan: while it may be impolite and it *feels* unwarranted, it's important to remember that is explicitly permitted behaviour (unfortunately, in many situations).

Comment: Permitted or not, a downvote should be explained. Call it common courtesy. Most SO users are victim to this unfortunately.

Comment: Yeah, thankfully they're only -2. And my downvoter seems to have retracted it, so now I join Carl as a prime suspect! :)

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the variable within the loop which will only return the last one. You should build an array of matches by declaring the variable outside of the loop or return the matches:

```
function $(elements) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(elements);
}
```

Or:

```
function $(elements) {
  var matches = document.querySelectorAll(elements);
  var items = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    items.push(matches[i]);   
  }
  return items;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You assign each item to `var item` in turn.

After you've assigned the last one, you return the current value of `item` (which is the last one).

Return `matches` and then loop over it to set the font size of each item in turn.

Comment: Well, *I'm* confused by the down-vote (to this answer, and to [Lumilo's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27138468/82548)).

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at what your `$` function is doing.

1. Select all items which match the query
2. Assign the first item in the list to `item`...
3. Assign the nth item to `item`
4. Return `item` which now contains the last element

So `$()` returns only the last element, and on that object, you are doing the assignment `.style.fontSize = '36px'`

There is no *simple* way to implement `$` to do exactly what you are trying to. You could try a function which is called like this:

```
$(selector, {
    fontSize : "36px"
});
```

It would look something like this:

```
function $(selector, properties) {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
        for (var j in properties) {
            matches[i].style[j] = properties[j];
        }
    }
}
```

I'd recommend you fully understand what this is doing before moving on.

Also, the way you have used document.readyState makes it redundant. You should enclose the function call in your document.readyState, not the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The variable item not is a array, then it is being overrided on each iteration loop.
Or define a array in order by save all selectors, or add the return in for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Of course! the variable `item` holds the current iteration match. After the `for` cycle completes, it will naturally hold the last matched element. Javascript is executed sequentially, meaning the `return` statement will be executed after the `for`cycle.

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to use chaining. This won't work with your current structure as your selector function will only ever return the last matched element from your querySlectorAll.

I think in this case it would be better to either pass a function that you want to do to each element or return an array/nodelist for another function to use;

```
function $(elements, method) {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll(elements);
    for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
         method(matches[i]);   
    }
}

$('div.test', function (elem) {elem.style.fontSize = '36px';});
```

Comment: I considered doing this, but I'm trying to 'replicate' jQuery's element selectors, so I'd prefer to keep the style syntax somewhat similar to what I have.

Comment: Then replicate jQuery, create an object with various methods; from each of those methods that you want to chain return the selection.

Answer (score -1):

```js
if(document.readyState === 'complete') {
    function $(elements) {
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll(elements);
        for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
             var item = matches[i];   
        }
        return item;
    }
}

$('div.test').style.fontSize = '36px';
```

```html
<div class="test">asdf</div>
<div class="asdfd">test</div>
<div class="test">test</div>
```

Comment: Hello, your answer is just a replication of the code in the question and it does not provide any information why you would keep the same could.